# How to programmatically assign noise to button from UITableView in another ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an array of sounds that populates a TableView.  When a user selects one of them, I want to assign that sound to a button in another view controller.  That view controller is currently working with a "default" sound that is assigned to the button.  What is the best way to do this?

**edit** I've edited to show my changes, but still doesn't seem to work.   Any thoughts?

**pickSound.m**

```
@interface pickSound ()

@end

@implementation pickSound

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.titleObjectsArray = @[@"Horn", @"Dog Barking", @"Whistle", @"Funny Noises",];

    self.soundObjectsArray = @[@"horn.wav", @"bark1.wav", @"whistle.wav", @"funny.wav",];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear: (BOOL)animated{

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.titleObjectsArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *previewSound = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PlayButtonPNG.png"];
    [previewSound setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.titleObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(indexPath.row ==0)
{
    sound = @"Horn";
}

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"pickedSound"]) {
        ViewController *cameraVC = (ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        cameraVC.soundId = sound;
    }
}
```

**ViewController.m (where button to play sound is located)**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "pictureViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@synthesize soundId;

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.soundId = soundId;

    if ([soundId isEqualToString:@"horn"]){
        NSURL *makeNoiseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle      mainBundle]pathForResource:@"horn" ofType:@".wav"]];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)makeNoiseURL, &SoudID);
    } else {
        NSURL *makeNoiseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle     mainBundle]pathForResource:@"horn" ofType:@".wav"]];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)makeNoiseURL, &SoudID);
    }
}

- (IBAction)makeNoise:(id)sender {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoudID);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I created an NSString that is assigned the value of whichever row is selected.  Pass that string to the 2nd VC using prepareforsegue.  use if statement to assign sound to play to button based on NSString Sound.

**picksound.m **

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedIndexPath = [self.titleObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([self.selectedIndexPath isEqual:@"Horn"]) {
        sound = @"Horn";
    } else if ([self.selectedIndexPath isEqual: @"Dog Barking"]) {
        sound = @"Dog Barking";
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"newVC" sender:self];
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    DestinationVC *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.selectedSound = sound;
}
```

**viewcontroller.m**

```
- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {
    if ([selectedSound isEqualToString:@"Horn"]) {
        NSURL *makeNoiseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"horn" ofType:@".wav"]];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)makeNoiseURL, &SoudId);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoudId);

    } else if ([selectedSound isEqualToString:@"Dog Barking"]) {
        NSURL *makeNoiseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"bark1" ofType:@".wav"]];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)makeNoiseURL, &SoudId);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoudId);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an **NSString** property in your *ViewController* class and set it when you make a selection in TableView. Remove that hard coded resource loading from **viewDidLoad** and use this property for resource name.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but for some reason I can't get the sound to play when I do this.  See the above edited post.  Any thoughts?

Comment: In your _prepareForSegue_ method put a break point and see if you are getting the correct value in _sound_ variable. In your **ViewController** class there is no need for this line of code

 ' self.soundID = soundID'

As you have already set this property from the source class. Put a breakpoint and check if the are coming correct. I see you have hard coded it for the first row only(index 0). Make sure you are hitting the right row.